# Can EU companies legally circumvent charging VAT by using a foreign subsidiary?

Tags: tax-law

Could an EU company open a subsidiary company outside of the EU and legally sell its services through it to citizens living in the EU?

Comment: Based on information from the US government available at https://www.export.gov/article?id=European-Union-How-the-EU-s-Value-Added-Tax-VAT-Impacts-U-S-Exports-2016, in sections III and IV, the answer appears to be: it's complicated and depends on the type of service, but for many services VAT must still be paid by the customer anyway. There may be specific rules against EU companies establishing subsidiaries for this purpose, though, so I'll leave a proper answer to others.

Answer (score 2):

### No

VAT is payable on the transaction - not the domicile of the vendor.